# while loop not working if there is only one element

Tags: bash, git, macos, shell

I'm trying to write a script that creates some changelogs. It looks at all of the commits since the previous tag and prepends a `-`  to every commit message.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tag_commits_reversed=$(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
tags=$(git describe --match "tag_prefix*" --abbrev=0 --tags $tag_commits_reversed)
commit_messages=$(git log $tags..@ --no-merges --pretty=format:"%s" -- . | while read line; do echo "- $line"; done)

echo $commit_messages
```

The output looks as follows:

`- commit_message_1 - commit_message_2 - commit_message_3`

However, if there has only been one single commit since the previous tag the `| while read line; do echo "- $line"; done` won't correctly prepend the `-`  to the single commit message.

I'd expect `- commit_message_1` but only get an empty output.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Instead of `| while read line; do echo "- $line"; done`, can't you change the format string to `--pretty=format:'- %s'` ?

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: See the [My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21) section of [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the problem at hand can be explained with this example:

```bash
read < <(printf %s foo) && echo "$REPLY"
read < <(printf '%s\n' bar) && echo "$REPLY"
```

which outputs:

```
bar
```

That is to say: if the input doesn't end with the expected delimiter (`\n` your case) then the `read` command evaluates to `false` and the `while read` loop ends prematurely.

A common workaround is to also check the size of the variable in the `while` condition:

```bash
... | while read line || (( ${#line} )); do ...
```

Comment: or `while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do`